# how can i get facebook page_id for my page?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to using facebook api in my site, I refer to other sites , they have a meta defining a page_id , and I see many acticle which their code exists this page_id . but how can I find this page_id value in developer.facebook.com?

[image]

Comment: Go to the URL graph.facebook.com/[your unique page name] and look for the value of "id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To get facebook id (using PC)

1. Click on *[toothed wheel](http://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851580_142488495957208_1588909839_n.png)* icon on upper right corner in your facebook profile.
2. In drop down menu, Select your page (this will opens up your page).
3. In Admin panel, Click on edit page button. Click "Update Page Info" form drop menu.
4. Last action will open information associated with page. Go down and find "Facebook Page ID"